# Using Pivot long using values based on column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am attempting to pivot a dataset so that the values in the long dataset are based on values in one of the columns. Here is an example of the data:

```
testdf <- data.frame('b'=rep(1:5, each=2), 'x'=rnorm(10, 0),'y'=rnorm(10, c(5,10)),'z'=rnorm(5, c(10,20)),'a'=rep(c(1, 2), 5))
```

If I pivot long and exclude `b` I get:

```
testdflong <- tidyr::pivot_longer(testdf, !c(b), names_to='lines', values_to='values')
```

Which repeats every value `x,y,z` for every `a=c(1,2)`. What I want to do is only choose the value of `z` based on `a`. I know that I could filter the wide data but in the real use case `a` might have more than 2 values and so will `z` and I don't want to have to filter the wide data on each 'a'.

```
resultdf <- testdf %>% filter(a==1)
resultdf <- bind_cols(resultdf, testdf %>% filter(a==2) %>% dplyr::select(z))
resultdflong <- tidyr::pivot_longer(resultdf, !c(b), names_to='lines', values_to='values')
```

But I want to skip the filtering and bind_cols step.

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(testdf, -c(a,b), names_to='lines', values_to='values') %>% filter(lines == "z")`?

Comment: DO you want to filter first `testdf %>% filter(a == 1) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -b, names_to = "lines")`

Comment: @JonSpring @akrun, I have added the desired result but I want to skip the filtering step because `a` might have more than 2 values.

Comment: your expected shows 25 observations.  Is that correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
testdf %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(a,b))  %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(name, a), values_from = value) %>%
  pivot_longer(-b, names_to = "lines", values_to = "values") %>%
  filter(lines %>% str_ends("1") | lines %>% str_starts("z")) %>%
  complete(b, lines = c("a", unique(lines)), fill = list(values = 1))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 25 × 3
       b lines values
   <int> <chr>  <dbl>
 1     1 a      1    
 2     1 x_1   -0.158
 3     1 y_1    4.11 
 4     1 z_1    9.62 
 5     1 z_2   19.1  
 6     2 a      1    
 7     2 x_1   -0.820
 8     2 y_1    6.13 
 9     2 z_1    9.25 
10     2 z_2   17.8  
# … with 15 more rows
```

Comment: This solution is incorrect because for each `b`, I want one x and y and two z's.

Comment: Edited, hopefully more like intended result.

Comment: Almost there (I don't need `a`) and your help inspired my solution.

Answer (score 0):

We could just replace the values in 'x', 'y' where a not equal to 1 to `NA` and then make use of `values_drop_na` in `pivot_longer` to remove those rows in the long formatted dataset

```
library(dplyr) # version>= 1.1.0
library(tidyr)
testdf %>%
   mutate(across(x:y, ~ case_match(a, 1~ .x))) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -b, names_to = 'lines', values_to = 'values', 
   values_drop_na = TRUE)%>% 
   filter((values == 1 & lines == 'a')| lines != 'a' )
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 25 × 3
       b lines values
   <int> <chr>  <dbl>
 1     1 x     -1.06 
 2     1 y      4.12 
 3     1 z      8.61 
 4     1 a      1    
 5     1 z     20.7  
 6     2 x     -0.148
 7     2 y      6.33 
 8     2 z     10.3  
 9     2 a      1    
10     2 z     20.7  
# … with 15 more rows
```

Comment: This solution is incorrect because it relies on me specifying the different values of 'not equal to' . I will still need to specify each contrast and the point of the question is to not have to do this.

Comment: @Fatm You said in your post not to use filter afterwards

Comment: @Fatm My update gets 25 observations.  I don't understand your point about relying of value 'not equal to', when you are using `filter` in your code as well as the accepted solution with str_starts

Comment: I use filter to get a minimal dataset. Sorry if that was confusing. I meant not to use filter to filter each unique case. Accepted answer was closest and by using pivot_wide and pivot_long inspired my solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me which is just a bit slimmer than Jon's solution is:

```
testdf1 <- testdf %>% 
              dplyr::select(b, z, a) %>% 
              tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = a, values_from=z)
testdf2 <- bind_cols(testdf %>% filter(a==1) %>% 
              dplyr::select(b, x, y), testdfw %>% 
              dplyr::select(!b))
testd2long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(testdf2, !b, names_to='lines', values_to='values')
```

Comment: Is this solution also using `a==1` which you mentioned as not to do?